# How can I move hundreds of files whose keyword(ID) of their file names are listed in a text file?

Tags: bash, files, mv

I need to move hundreds of files whose name include an ID number and these number are listed line by line in a text file.

For example:

```
The content of `ID.txt`:

1231245
1435466
3454656
3356646
```

Files I need to move:

```
1231245_134.fasta
1231245_134.dna
1435466_345.fasta
1435466_345.dna
3454656_789.fasta
3454656_789.dna
3356646_104.fasta
3356646_104.dna
```

Answer (score 1):

- You can give `grep` the argument `-f FILE` to match against expressions in `FILE`, one per line.
- `ID.txt` needs to be modified slightly by `sed` so that it only match exactly what you want: a `^` at the start of each line to make the number match at the start of a line, and `_` at the end so a `123` won't match `123123_`.
- `ls -1` will list one file per line.
- `xargs -I FOOBAR` replaces occurrences of FOOBAR with the input line rather than appending the input line.

So:

```
sed -e 's/^/^/' -e 's/$/_/' /path/to/ID.txt > /tmp/ID_regexp.txt
cd /old/dir
ls -1 | grep -f /tmp/ID_regexp.txt | xargs -I FILE mv FILE /new/dir
```

Comment: This does not work reliably. For example, if ID.txt contains the line `123`, a file `345_123.txt` would be moved.

Comment: @user1934428 Fixed.

Comment: I think there is one more to fix. Assuming that ID.txt contains the line `abc*def`, this would incorrectly move the file `abdef_123.txt`. BTW, you can run into a race condition, if the script is executed simultaneously by two processes, because you are using a fixed filename for the temporary file. Better to put the process ID into the file name and make sure that the file is erased afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

How about (if your shell provides "process substitution")

```
. <(sed 's/^/echo mv /; s/$/* \/target/' ID.txt)
```

Remove the echo if happy with the result.

**EDIT** (proposed by Stéphane Chazelas)

```
sed 's|.*|mv -- &_* /target/|' ID.txt | sh -v -n
```

Remove the `-n` if happy with the result.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file names don't contain blank, newlines, backslashes or quotes, and a shell like ksh, zsh or bash with support for process substitution, you could do:

```
join -t_ <(printf '%s\n' *_* | sort -t_ -k1,1) <(sort ID.txt) |
  xargs sh -c 'exec mv -- "$@" /target' sh
```

Comment: Help me out - what does the trailing `sh {} +` do? I can't see a difference with or without it.

Comment: @RudiC, my bad. I included those out of habit of using `find ... -exec sh -c code sh {} +`. It doesn't apply to `xargs` of course.

Answer (score 0):

A pure `bash` solution:

```
while IFS= read -r p; do mv ${p}* /target; done < ID.txt
```

- `< ID.txt` gives the file as input
- `while IFS= read -r p` llops trough the lines

  - `mv ${p}* /target` move all files starting with the number in the file to the `/target` directory.

---

You can write `echo` in front of the `mv` command to control which commands would be executed:

```
$ while IFS= read -r p; do echo mv ${p}* /target; done < ID.txt
mv 1231245_134.dna 1231245_134.fasta /target
mv 1435466_345.dna 1435466_345.fasta /target
mv 3454656_789.dna 3454656_789.fasta /target
mv 3356646_104.dna 3356646_104.fasta /target
```